# Mysql connection with Flask python 3.7 get some issue

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

**Environment:**

On my local computer:
Python 3.7.7
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 1.0.1

The remote server:
Ubuntu
MariaDB 10.1.44

**Problem:**

I am developing a web app with Flask on my local computer which needs to access my remote Mysql server.
I get this error message on my browser:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'Nino'@'lneuilly-657-1-15-173.w193-248.abo.wanadoo.fr' (using password: YES)")
```

**What I tried:**

I enable remote access on my Mysql server in my Plesk dashboard.
I gave full permissions to my Mysql user.
I made a test with a normal MySQL connection on a python file which was successful. Please see below the code that I tried:

```
try:    
    import mysql.connector
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                        host="217.1.1.1",
                        port=3306,
                        user="John",
                        passwd="123456",
                        database="wp_fi1lb"
                    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    print("Mysql connection 1 succesfull")
except ValueError:
    print("Error mysql connection 1")


from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
app = Flask(__name__)

try:
    app.config['SECRET_KEY']='secret'
    app.config['MYSQL_HOST']='217.1.1.1'
    app.config['MYSQL_USERNAME']='John'
    app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']='123456'
    app.config['MYSQL_DB']='wp_fi1lb'
    app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS']='DictCursor'

    mysql = MySQL(app)
    cursor=mysql.connection.cursor()
    print("Mysql connection 2 succesfull")
except ValueError:
    print("Error mysql connection 2")
```

And see the output:

```
Mysql connection 1 succesful
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/wamp64/www/dashboard/test.py", line 30, in <module>
    cursor=mysql.connection.cursor()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

You can see that the first way to connect to the MySQL database was successful whereas the second way failed.

So I tried another way after I have made some Google search. I used flask-mysql this time instead of flask-mysqldb:

```
try:    
    import mysql.connector
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                        host="217.1.1.1",
                        port=3306,
                        user="John",
                        passwd="123456",
                        database="wp_fi1lb"
                    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    print("Mysql connection 1 succesfull")
except ValueError:
    print("Error mysql connection 1")


from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
#from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
app = Flask(__name__)

try:
    app.config['SECRET_KEY']='secret'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST']='217.1.1.1'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT']='3306'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USERNAME']='John'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD']='123456'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB']='wp_fi1lb'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_CURSORCLASS']='DictCursor'

    mysql = MySQL(app)
    #cursor=mysql.connection.cursor()
    cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
    print("Mysql connection 2 succesfull")
except ValueError:
    print("Error mysql connection 2")
```

The output:

```
Mysql connection 1 succesfull
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/wamp64/www/dashboard/test.py", line 33, in <module>
    cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

As you can see, we have the exact same issue.

I don't see what am I doing wrong?
Why should I use flask-mysqldb if I can connect with mysql.connector?

Comment: just check if you are remotely able to access the database or not with same credentials or not, i thinkit is better to use sqlalchemy as it is good with mysql db and others one

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I did succeed to remotely access with same credential with mysql.connector (see success connection 1 in output and source code)

Comment: in case 2 , intitalise app like in documentation https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/